# Problemas implementando la variable REPORT_COUNT en ireport

Tags: java, ireport, reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es que la numeración se vea discriminada por cada paciente y no por cada registro que encuentre de acuerdo a la consulta. Por ejemplo:  El paciente Acosta mauro tendría que tener la numeración 2 y no la 3 y los demás registros donde no aparece un paciente, quiere decir que pertenecen al paciente de arriba y no requiere numeración.
No estoy logrando dar con la solución. Demás está decir que Agradecería algún aporte de ustedes que me pueda ayudar.. muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que necesitas es crear tu propia variable que incremente cuando si hay paciente, tambien debes tener una condicion para mostrar esa variable igual solo cuando existe el paciente, hace mucho no toco reportes pero espero darte la idea

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!!. Eso que mencionas, donde lo hago? Dentro del plugin de ireport? Pido disculpas por mi ignorancia, estoy arrancando recién

Comment: En la consulta que hago dentro del plugin, se recuperan los datos que aparecen en la imagen, nada mas que se repiten los nombres de los pacientes. Entonces para solucionar eso lo que hice fue cambiar una propiedad del field para que no muestren valores repetidos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que hice es crear una variable  `auxiliar`  para guardar el paciente
de este modo la variable que hace la funcion de contar, estara haciendo una comparación del valor del paciente en el que va la iteración con el valor anterior, si es diferente, entonces hay que incrementar el contador, la variable auxiliar se inicializa con el paciente, y se esta comparando en cada iteracion, se actualiza cada vez que paciente cambie de valor

```
    <field name="paciente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="prescripcion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="unidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="auxiliar" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{paciente}.equals($V{auxiliar})?$V{auxiliar}:$F{paciente}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{paciente}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
```

Ahora la variable `contador` se inicializa en 1, de ahi se va comparando el dato de paciente con el dato auxiliar, y si son diferentes, el contador suma 1

```
<variable name="contador" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{paciente}.equals($V{auxiliar})?$V{contador}:$V{contador}+1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="auxiliar" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{paciente}.equals($V{auxiliar})?$V{auxiliar}:$F{paciente}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{paciente}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
```

Ahora solo agrega un textfield con la variable contador

Los resultados esperados al hacer el preview del reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Espero te sirva y puedas adaptarlo a tu necesidad

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!!! es exactamente lo que quería hacer y lo pude implementar!!! Muy agradecido